# Web security audit issues with asp .net core 3

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, content-security-policy

I am trying to pass with a B or A grade on http://observatory.mozilla.org and I am getting a 'C' grade. I implemented middleware to set the security headers and cookies but still don't understand how to fix a few things. All my scripts and javascript is loaded via src tags and no inline styles. Can someone give me ideas to fix the various problems I am having I can't seem to find a fix for?

[image]

[image]

My content-security-policy is **default-src https: 'self'; object-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; base-uri 'none'; font-src https: data:**

My cookie shows :   .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.GOAuSILz_xU=CfDJ8D3hsoQ239JIszuJwoP5ibPL-N9p62srnnwCdREtuQ0bGMft1N7bQulP3alJ4DsTVOUX_i76TbLdQtUjp1UgKAFup-FCj46R5vBSBujuDbXJDSbtQ2xgICsW_CofHqShdiLQj8xefPjmQvYYQMEL2d0; path=/; samesite=strict; httponly

Here is my code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict;
            options.Secure = HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment() ? CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest : CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            options.HttpOnly = Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.HttpOnlyPolicy.None;
        });

        services.AddSession(opts =>
        {
            opts.Cookie.IsEssential = true; // make the session cookie Essential,
            opts.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
            opts.Cookie.SecurePolicy = HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment() ? CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest : CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        });

        services.AddSession();
        services.Configure<Credentials>(Configuration.GetSection("Credentials"));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseSecurityHeadersMiddleware(
           new SecurityHeadersBuilder()
               .AddDefaultSecurePolicy());

        app.UseSession();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        //app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Here is web.config if you need it

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
        <add name="Cache-Control" value="public, max-age=31536000" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: are you running the test over HTTPS?

Comment: Yes. I have cert and code auto forwards to HTTPS in .net core middleware

Comment: options.HttpOnly = Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.HttpOnlyPolicy.None might be the problem, use .Always

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure services:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(opts =>
            {
                opts.CheckConsentNeeded = _ => true;
                opts.HttpOnly = Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.HttpOnlyPolicy.Always;
                opts.Secure = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                opts.MinimumSameSitePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Strict;
            });
            services.AddSession(opts =>
            {
                opts.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                opts.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                opts.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                opts.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Strict;
            });
```

And don't forget to add UseCookiePolicy middleware:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseCookiePolicy(); //here
app.UseSession();
app.UseRouting();
```

[image: Cookie]

Comment: Can you tell me why HTTPOnly is set to true versus how I have it? I am still learning how this works. I am serving this page over HTTPS and it auto forwards from HTTP to HTTPS in .net core middleware.

Comment: When you set a cookie with the HttpOnly flag, it informs the browser that this special cookie should only be accessed by the server. Any try to access the cookie from client side script is strictly forbidden. Of course, this presumes you have: A modern web browser.
Attribution link: https://latesthackingnews.com/2017/07/03/what-is-httponly-cookie/

Comment: I did your changes and now Chrome gives me this?  A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://fontawesome.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Comment: I have this code in my HTML <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/07918087aa.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: @kyleb the problem seems to be in the html file